# Stuck on a Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations, symmetry, geometric-transformation

> $ABCD$ is a square, $E$ is a midpoint of side $BC$, points $F$ and $G$ are on the diagonal $AC$ so that $|AF|=3\ \text{cm}$, $|GC|=4\ \text{cm}$ and $\angle{FEG}=45 ^{\circ}$.  Determine the length of the segment $FG$.

How can I approach this problem, preferably without trigonometry?

[image]

Comment: Actually, I think it is quite easy with trigonometry : you can write the law of cosines in triangles $ECG$, $EFC$ and $EFG$. From this you get a relation between $x$ and the length $L$ of the side of your square. Then you have also $(7+x)^2 = 2L^2$, and the two relations together give you $x$.

But without trigonometry, I have no idea...

Comment: One reflection proves that G is on AD.  A second reflection proves that AF=AC/4.

Comment: Seeing the lengths 3cm, 4cm and half of a right angle, I somehow think of x=5

Comment: This is quite a common pattern in elementary geometry: half a right angle, stuck in a frame of right angles. Generally speaking, this can be solved by constructing 'rotationally similar' triangles. It even has a name in Chinese geometry education: the *half-angle model*.

Comment: @Trebor Is there a source for such problems/exercises?

Comment: Take any Chinese geometry book for middle school students, and there will be mountains of similar problems. For problems on this level, I do not have much information for English materials.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Following solution uses no concept of concyclic or similar triangles, only rotation and Pythagoras theorem.*

Let $O$ be a midpoint of a segment $AC$.

Rotate $G$ for $-90^{\circ}$ around $E$ to a new point $K$. This rotation takes $C$ to $O$ and $O$ to $B$, so $K$ is on a segment $BO$ (which is a part of diagonal $BD$)

Then $EK=EG$ so $E$ is on perpendicular bisector of $KG$. Since $\angle KEF = \angle FEG = 45^{\circ}$ line $EG$ is perpendicular bisector for $KG$ so $FK = FG = x$.

Since $ FO = {x+1\over 2}$ we can use Pythagoras theorem in triangle $\triangle FOK$:

$$ x^2 = 4^2+\Big({x+1\over 2}\Big)^2 \implies x=5$$

[image]

Comment: +1. Nicer still! Interestingly, I had just returned to post an addendum to [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3131417/409), recognizing a Pythagorean relation I had originally missed. I hadn't had time to give much thought to its geometric interpretation, but then I saw that your answer provided exactly that interpretation. Thanks for saving me the trouble! :)

Answer (score 26):

[image]

Let $H$ be the midpoint of $AC$ and $\angle EIC= 90^{\circ}$. We can observe that $$FH+3=HG+4,\quad FH+HG=x.$$ So we obtain $HG=\frac{x-1}2$. Since two corresponding angles are congruent; $\angle FEG =\angle EHG=45^{\circ}$ and $\angle EGF=\angle HGE$, we have that $\triangle FEG$ and $\triangle EHG$ are similar to each other. This gives $$FG:EG=EG:HG\implies EG^2 = FG\cdot HG=\frac{x(x-1)}2.$$ Now, note that $EI=\frac14 AC=\frac{x+7}4$ and $IG=IH-GH=\frac{x+7}{4}-\frac{x-1}2=\frac{9-x}{4}$. Since $\triangle EIG$ is a right triangle, by Pythagorean theorem, we find that
$$
EG^2=\frac{x(x-1)}{2}=EI^2+IG^2=\frac{(x+7)^2}{16}+\frac{(9-x)^2}{16},
$$ which implies $x=5  $ or $x=-\frac{13}3$. Since $x>0$, we get $x=5$.

Comment: I would suggest to remove the angle also from the drawing (instead both angles of $45^{\circ}$ can be shown). By the way what a nice program do you use for the drawings?

Comment: @user I just updated my figure, thank you. By the way, the program I used is the [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en). It provides an online workspace and even cloud services if you sign up!

Comment: I'm surprised we didn't draw the circle through EFG whose center, O, is the right angle of the triangle FOG.  I can see that the perpendicular bisector of OC is EG, transporting length 4 cm to one leg.  Transporting 3 cm to the other leg thwarts me.

Answer (score 13):

Let $O$ be a midpoint of a segment $AC$.

Rotate $F$ for $90^{\circ}$ around $E$ to a new point $H$. This rotation takes $O$ to $C$.

Then $EF=EH$ and $\angle FEH = 90^{\circ}$ so $EG$ is angle bisector for $\angle FEH$ so $GH = GF = x$.

It is easy to see that $$CH = FO = {x+1\over 2}$$

Now $FHCE$ is cyclic quadrilateral since $\angle CFE = \angle CHE$ so $$\angle FCH = \angle FEH =90^{\circ}$$

Finaly we use Pythagoras theorem in triangle $\triangle CGH$:

$$ x^2 = 4^2+\Big({x+1\over 2}\Big)^2 \implies x=5$$

[image]

Comment: Your solution encourages me to think that there may be even more geometric solutions.

Answer (score 6):

With the figure as labeled below, define
$$a := |AA^\prime| \qquad b := |BB^\prime| \qquad c := |A^\prime B^\prime| \qquad d := |A^\prime M|$$

Note that the perpendicular from midpoint $M$ to the diagonal necessarily quadrisects that diagonal; moreover, $\overline{MM^\prime}\cong\overline{BM^\prime}$.

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\triangle A^\prime M^\prime M \text{ is a right triangle} 
&\quad\to\quad d^2 = \left(c+b-\frac14(a+b+c)\right)^2+\left(\frac14(a+b+c)\right)^2 \tag{1}\\[4pt]
\triangle A^\prime B^\prime M \sim \triangle A^\prime M B \text{ (Angle-Angle)} &\quad\to\quad \frac{|A^\prime M|}{|A^\prime B^\prime|} = \frac{|A^\prime B|}{|A^\prime M|} \quad\to\quad d^2 = c(b+c) \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Equating $d^2$ with $d^2$ yields
$$3c^2 + 2c(a-b) - a^2 + 2 a b - 5 b^2 = 0 \tag{3}$$
which suggests that there's nothing *inherently* Pythagorean about the general values $a$, $b$, $c$ (but see the Addendum). However, for the specific values $a=3$ and $b=4$, we have
$$0 = 3 c^2 - 2c - 65 = (c-5)(3c+13) \quad\to\quad c = 5 \tag{4}$$
where we have ignored the "obviously"-extraneous solution $c=-13/3$. $\square$

---

**Note.** The extraneous solution from $(4)$ becomes valid if we interpret the problem as saying that "lines $\overleftrightarrow{MA^\prime}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{MB^\prime}$ make a $45^\circ$ angle".

[image]

---

**Addendum.** I notice that there is actually *something* inherently Pythagorean about general $a$, $b$, $c$. We can write $(3)$ as
$$\left(\frac{- a + b + c}{2} \right)^2 + b^2 = c^2 \tag{3'}$$
implying that $|-a+b+c|/2$, $|b|$, $|c|$ make a right triangle. (With $a=3$ and $b=4$, the two solutions to $(4)$ correspond to a $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle, and a $5$-$12$-$13$ triangle scaled by $1/3$.) I hadn't seen a way to make $(3')$ *obvious* in the figure (I was just playing with the algebra); however, by interesting coincidence, [@greedoid's new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3132209/409) seems to show exactly this! Here's a version of @greedoid's figure, with a more-arbitrary relationship between lengths $a$ and $b$.

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution +1. You could get a formula (2) also by the power of the point $A'$ with respect to circumcircle of the triangle $BB'M$.

Comment: @greedoid: I thought of that. But, with the power-of-a-point approach, I'd have to explain how I knew that $\overline{A^\prime M}$ is actually *tangent* to that circumcircle. Of course, that tangency follows from some angle considerations; but then, so does the similarity argument, and the latter seems a bit more immediate (especially since the power-of-a-point result is effectively a consequence of that similarity, anyway).

Comment: @Blue Please kindly state your choice of best answer.

Comment: @blackened: I believe greedoid revealed the true, beating heart of the problem by constructing the right triangle corresponding to the Pythagorean relation I've called $(3^\prime)$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an attempt using the method of "have a hunch, then confirm it works", which probably follows the method by which the problem was first created. Intuiting where some missing lines ought to be can be helpful sometimes!

---

Begin with the following figure, with dimensions as given; we will show that filling in $z=4$ will force $y=3$, and also $x=5$, which is the answer we're looking for.

[image: Figure with relevant lines added]

First observe that the angle at $E$ is equal to $\pi/4$ or $45^{\circ}$. [see below]

Now, because we have a bunch of similar triangles (the two meeting vertically at $G$, the two meeting vertically at $F$, and the right-angled ones along the right-hand side), we observe:

$2d/d = (x+y)/z$

$d/ (\frac{1}{3}d) = (x+z)/y$

$d/2d = (z/\sqrt{2})/(\frac{4}{3}d)$

Now if we set $z=4$, a little bit of linear algebra (or simple substitution if you will) gives us $d=3\sqrt{2}$, $y=3$, and $x=5$.

Notice how removing the continuations of the lines $EF$ and $EG$ makes everything look really hard!

---

*Proof of the claim about the angle*:  This is because of a "fun fact" you may have discovered by playing around on squared graphing paper: the vectors $(2,1)$ and $(3,-1)$ (or suitable rotations of these) meet at that angle. You can prove this by reflecting one in the other using the standard formula from vector geometry: let $v=(2,1)$ and $n=(1,3)$ (which is orthogonal to $(3,-1)$). The standard reflection-in-a-line formula $v-2\frac{v\cdot n}{n\cdot n} n$ gives us

$(2,1) - 2\frac{5}{10}(1,3) = (2,1) - (1,3) = (1,-2)$

which is orthogonal to $(2,1)$; this implies that the reflection line $(3,-1)$ bisects that right angle, i.e. is at $\pi/4$ (or $45^{\circ}$) to $(2,1)$. $\square$

Answer (score 3):

Let $DE$ intersect $AC$ at $G'$. Then $G'C:G'A=CE:AD=1:2$, hence $3G'C=AC$.

Let the perpendicular bisector of $BE$ intersect $AC$ at $F'$. Easy to see that $4AF'=AC$.

Note that $F'E=F'B=F'D$. Hence $F'$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle BED$, so $\angle DF'E = 2\angle DBE = 2\cdot 45^\circ=90^\circ$. It follows that $\angle F'EG'=45^\circ$.

Observe that $$\frac{AF'}{G'C} = \frac{AC/4}{AC/3}=\frac 34 = \frac{AF}{GC}.$$

If $AF'>AF$ then by the above equality we also have $CG'>CG$, hence $45^\circ = \angle FEG > \angle F'EG' = 45^\circ$, a contradiction. Similarly we rule out the possibility $AF'<AF$.

Hence $AF'=AF$, which means that $CG'=CG$, so $F'=F$ and $G'=G$. Therefore $AC = 4AF = 12 \mathrm{cm}$, and

$$FG = AC - AF - GC = 12\mathrm{cm} - 3\mathrm{cm} - 4\mathrm{cm} = 5\mathrm{cm}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Drop perpendiculars $FH, EI$ and $FJ$ and label $BH=y$, $EH=z$ and $\angle GEI=\alpha$:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Use the similarity of $\triangle FEH$ and $\triangle EIG$:
$$\frac{GI}{HE}=\frac{EI}{FH} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{4-CI}{z}=\frac{CI}{y+2z}\Rightarrow \\
\frac{4-\frac{y+z}{\sqrt{2}}}{z}=
\frac{\frac{y+z}{\sqrt{2}}}{y+2z}\Rightarrow \\
\frac{4\sqrt{2}-y-z}{z}=\frac{y+z}{y+2z}\Rightarrow\\
3z^2+(4y-8\sqrt{2})z+y^2-4\sqrt{2}y=0 \stackrel{y=\frac3{\sqrt{2}}}{\Rightarrow} \\
6z^2-4\sqrt{2}z-15=0 \Rightarrow \\
z=\frac3{\sqrt{2}}.$$
Hence:
$$x+7=2(y+z)\sqrt{2}=12 \Rightarrow x=5.$$

Answer (score 2):

Calling

$$
AF = a\\
FG=x\\
GC = b\\
EC = c\\
E = (X_0, Y_0)\\
O = \left(a+\frac x2, \frac x2\right)
$$

Considering in the plane $X\times Y$ the square diagonal as the $X$ axis with $A$ at the origin, we have

$$
\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(a+x+b)= 2c\\
x = \sqrt2 r\\
\left(X_0-\left(a+\frac x2\right)\right)^2+\left(Y_0-\frac x2\right)^2= r^2\\
X_0 = a+x+b -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}c\\
Y_0 = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}c
$$

Here $r$ represents the radius for the circle which intersects the $X$ axis at $F, G$ such that $\angle FEG = \frac{\pi}{4}$ is the angle subtended by arc $AB$

Solving for $x,r,X_0,Y_0$ we get at

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 x& =& \frac{1}{3} \left(b-a+2 \sqrt{a^2-2 b a+4 b^2}\right) \\
 c& =& \frac{a+2 b+\sqrt{a^2-2 b a+4 b^2}}{3 \sqrt{2}} \\
 r& =& \frac{b-a+2 \sqrt{a^2-2 b a+4 b^2}}{3 \sqrt{2}} \\
 X_0&=&\frac{1}{2} \left(a+2 b+\sqrt{a^2-2 b a+4 b^2}\right) \\
 Y_0&=&\frac{1}{6} \left(a+2 b+\sqrt{a^2-2 b a+4 b^2}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

giving after substitution $x = 5$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without trigonometry or algebra, to find the length of $FG$.

With the figure and conditions as posted, construct circles with centers $F$, $G$ and radii $FA$, $GC$. Let the circle centered on $G$ cross $AC$, $BC$, $DC$ at $J$, $K$, $L$, and join $GK$ and $GL$.

Collinear $GK, GL$ are thus a diameter of the circle about $G$ and perpendicular to $AC$.

On $BA$ make $BM=BK$, and join $MK$, $MJ$, and $JK$.

Since $MBK$ and $ABC$ are isosceles right triangles sharing the angle at $B$ $$MK\parallel AJ$$
[[image: length of <span class=]$FG$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTpv4.png)
And since$$AM=CK=JK$$and$$AM\parallel JK$$then $AJKM$ is a parallelogram and$$AJ=MK=CG=4$$

Therefore$$FJ=AJ-AF=4-3=1$$ and$$FG=FJ+JG=1+4=5$$

Comment: How did you ascertain that $GJMK$ is a rectangle? You don't know $\angle KMJ$ or $\angle MJG$, do you?

Comment: @Jens-point well taken.  See if revised argument is better.

Comment: @Blue--Right, I had tried making tangents at $J$ and $K$, but couldn't prove $M$ must be on $AB$.  So I made $BM=BK$ and tried to go from there.  But I agree the argument was still incomplete.  See if you think the revised argument meets the objection.

Comment: Your argument cannot work because you are not using the $45^\circ$ angle info. Essentially you are trying to prove that any square whose diagonal has a $3$ cm bit in one corner and a $4$ cm bit in the other corner, must have a $5$ cm bit in the middle. This is not true.

Comment: You're right. $AJ=MK$ for other positions of $G$, but $MK$ although parallel is not generally equal to $GC$. So I can't conclude $AJ=GC=4$. Thanks for the light.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some calculus, I figured out to solve this problem. Let's draw the vertical V that goes through E, and call $\alpha$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha$ the angles we get on the left and right of the 45° angle cut by V and call c the length of the side of the square. We can then do some trigonometry to get :

- $c \cdot tan(\alpha) - (c-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}) = c \cdot tan(\alpha)$ (Continue the line EF to cut AD)
- $ tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha) = c \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}-1$ (G is $\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}$ away vertically from the right side and $\frac{c}{2}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}$ away horizontally from the middle)

With a little trigo, we have 2 equations in $c$ and $tan(\alpha)$ that we can solve, which allow us to solve the whole problem. This makes me think that there is no "simple" answer without trigo :(

Edit : Well, seems there was a simple answer afterall. Really nice proof, I'm glad I was wrong !

Answer (score 0):

I do not like it. This is not a geometry problem; it is indeed a puzzle where you have to find this coincidence, which occurs only if $AF:GC=3:4$.

[image]

If we can find/prove that $GDF\angle=45^\circ$ in some different way, then we can define the point $P$ that as the reflection of $C$ about $DE$ and the reflection of $A$ about $DF$. Due to $FPD\angle=DPG\angle=45^\circ$, the triangle $FGP$ is right-angled and its legs are $PF=AF=3$, $PG=CG=4$, so $FG=5$.

Comment: I don't understand it. Is this solution or just an idea how to prove it?

Comment: No solution, no idea. Just a demonstration, that somebody took this configuration and converted it to a puzzle.

Comment: No, this configuration has no free parameter, it is a concrete picture.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the red lines:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The steps:

1) Draw $EO=OK$ and $KP$ parallel to $EG$ so that $\triangle CGE$ and $\triangle OPK$ are congruent, in particular, $OP=4$.

2) Draw $KM$ so that $MO=OG$, hence $\triangle KMO$ and $\triangle OGE$ are congruent (two sides and angle between them are equal, i.e. $MO=OG, KO=OE, \angle KOM=\angle EOG=45^\circ$).

3) $\triangle AKM$ and $\triangle CEG$ are congruent (because $\triangle KMO$ and $OGE$ are congruent)

4) $\triangle KPM$ is isosceles ($KP=KM=EG$).

5) $KT$ is perpendicular to $PM$ (because $\triangle AKM$ and $\triangle KTO$ are symmetric (reflective) around it.

6) If we label $PT=z$, then $AP=3-z,TM=z,MO=4-2z,OG=3-z$

7) Since $MO=OG \Rightarrow 4-2z=3-z \Rightarrow z=1$ and $x=z+4-2z+3-z=7-2z=5.$

**Note:** No formula (or theorem) is used.

Comment: @greedoid, I am curious if you find this solution worthwhile (I'm not pretending to the bounty). Obviously, the first step should be $EC=EO=OK$. Any flaws in reasoning?

Comment: First let me apologize for my late reply, I just don't now why i wasn't notified about this comment. Anyway I'm not sure about 5). Why is $T $ a midpoint of $PM$? In whole analysis before you never mentioned the $T$. How is it related to $PM$?

Comment: because $\triangle AKM$ and $\triangle KPO$ (sorry, $\triangle KTO$ was a typo) are congruent.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But anyway I still do not understand why is T midpoint of PM. If $T$ is a midpoint then this triangles are symmetric, but vice versa? I'm not sure.